# Laravel session data not sticking across page loads

Tags: php, session, laravel, laravel-4

I tried running the following code:

```
Session::put('progress', '5%');

dd(Session::get('progress'));
```

This will show '5%' in the dump.

If I rerun the same page but comment out `Session::put('progress', '5%');` so that only the `dd()` line is called, I get a null value instead of the 5% values stored in the previous page load.

Here is my sessions config, so I know it should be storing the data:

```
'driver' => 'native',
'lifetime' => 120,
'expire_on_close' => false,
```

Why is Laravel not storing the session data across page loads?

Comment: I believe it is because you are killing the script with `dd()` before Laravel finish its lifecycle the value is not stored into the session. Try putting a value without the `dd` to complete the full Laravel lifecycle. Then, after that, try to retrieve it.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The problem is because you are killing the script before Laravel finishes its application lifecycle, so the values put in session (but not yet stored) got killed too.

When a Laravel application lifecycle starts, any value `put` in `Session` are not yet stored until the application lifecycle ends. That is when any value `put` in `Session` will be finally/really `stored`.

If you check [the source](http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Session.Store.html#107-121) you will find the same aforementioned behavior:

```
 public function put($key, $value)
 {
     $all = $this->all();

     array_set($all, $key, $value);

     $this->replace($all);
 }
```

---

If you want to test it, do the following:

1. Store a value in session without killing the script.

   ```
   Route::get('test', function() {
       Session::put('progress', '5%');
       // dd(Session::get('progress'));
   });
   ```
2. Retrieve the value already *stored*:

   ```
   Route::get('test', function() {
       // Session::put('progress', '5%');
       dd(Session::get('progress'));
   });
   ```

Comment: Very nice! Thanks for not only the solution but the granular explanation of the plumbing. :)

Comment: Can I force Laravel to immediately write the session data? I'm trying to use this to store progress on a process accessed through AJAX.

Comment: where does laravel session store the values? I can not see them in the session storag.

Comment: In a fresh install the session storage driver is disk file.

Comment: @eComEvo you can use `Session::save();`

Comment: but thats contrary to natural way session works in php as `$_SESSION` saves it on spot.

Comment: @RubensMariuzzo I tried the same as you told in example however next time I get null please help me I am using Laravel 8.*

Comment: You save my day, voted. I keep killing the script before session save.

Answer (score 49):

Rubens Mariuzzo's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23917702/439427) is very good. I just want to add that if you need the data to be stored immediately you could use the save method:

```
Session::put('progress', '5%');
Session::save();
```

Comment: Thanks Man. you saved my day.

Comment: Does this work for you even if you call a "die()" right after?  For some reason, even if I call Session::save(), it's the same result.  I have to return the response in order to make it work for some reason.  I'm using L5.2 and L5.3

Comment: Just noticed that this case does not work when the session driver is set to "cookies", because cookies are not saved immediately, and are queued up to send as a batch all together at the end of the request.  That means, if you dd(), it's not gonna work!  Sux0rs...

Answer (score 1):

I moved the session middleware

> \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class

to the property $middleware in

> app/Http/Kernel.php

In this case, you need to remove it from the web group ($middlewareGroups)

[image]

It helped me, I hope it helps you too

Answer (score 0):

For me, even after data has been stored to session properly:

```
    dd(Session::all());
```

returns nothing, but:

```
    print_r(Session::all());
```

returns all session data!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I flashed the variable in one request and then put it into session in another request (with the same name).

Unfortunatelly, terminating method went through all the previously flashed properties and cleaned my newly created session property (it was flushed in previous request so laravel thought it was no longer required and couldn't tell it was newly created). I figured it out debugging `Kernel->terminateMiddleware` method. You can put a breakpoint in terminating method. At some stage it reaches `Store->ageFlashData`. This is the method responsible for deleting my property.

Answer (score 0):

Often, my app would store the session variables, but sometimes (~5% of the time) it would not.
I tried multiple approaches, however, this is the only one that has been working reliably (so far):

```
$request->session()->put('key', 'value');
$request->session()->save();
```

Cheers :)