# Laravel 5 doesn't store session variable between pages

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5, persistence

I am pretty new to Laravel 5 and I'm trying to store some variables in session to use them on other pages. The problem is that everytime I go to another page or I refresh the page, the session is empty. I tried using `Session::get('key')`, I tried using `session('key')` as Laravel documentation says, I tried with `$request->session()->get('key')` and finally I tried ussing my own session handler which is assigning values directly to global $_SESSION variable, but no result.

I tried the solution from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23917409/laravel-session-data-not-sticking-across-page-loads), but when I refresh my page, session is empty. It work fine just if I assign a value right before I use it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: look, the problem is not in laravel. it is in your code. create an http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and post it here. No one can tell what you are doing wrong if they have no idea what you are doing

Comment: @RajKamal sorry, I had many code samples and didn't know which one to post here

Comment: @ThomasKim Thanks a lot! The problem was solved moving my routes to the web middleware. I think that was the only thread that I missed on Laravel and session..