Session sometimes not saving values but when I add save() it fixes the issue
I've been struggling with finding the reason for sessions not saving randomly (and often).
In my case the session is saved on page load:
// in the controller
public function some_view(Request $request)
{
    $request->session()->put('key1', 'value1');

    // ... some more code...

    return view(...);
}

Then on another page or function somewhere when I try to get the key1 value it is null:
// in another method in the project, maybe another controller or mail function
class SomeEmail extends Mailable
{
    public $some_value;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->some_value = session('key1'); // but it's null very often (but not always)
    }
 
}

Then I came across this post of a very old Laravel version (v4): https://stackoverflow.com/a/37409073/10847401
which suggests to use the save() method when I put values:
    public function some_view(Request $request)
    {
        $request->session()->put('key1', 'value1');
        $request->session()->save(); // <-- added this
    
        // ... some more code...
    
        return view(...);
    }

The save() method is not in the docs but it still exists in the API for Laravel 10: https://laravel.com/api/10.x/Illuminate/Contracts/Session/Session.html#method_save
And from some reason that worked and there are no longer times where the session value is null in that case
My Laravel project was updated from Version 7 to 10 gradually so maybe that could have also caused some issues?

what session driver you use? check the session.lifetime if is short..

Thank you. File driver. session lifetime is not short, and also the problem happens immediately after I run the method that saves it and then go to the page that uses it. Like it's null 5 seconds later

you can try to use the global helper like session(['key1' => 'value1']); instead ot the $request, in the mail you don't have the request.. to debug the use session()->all();

do you make any ajax call or reload the page? remember that  web middleware maintains the session

It happens with the session help as well. And when the problem occurs, request->session()->all() shows that they key doesn't exist at all (so it wasn't even set and that's why the value is null when I try to get it from another page). There might be ajax calls but that would happen after the page finished loading and calling another route completely

you can try to use this flash data. Use the debugger, check where your data is going, and put the ->exists() to see what route the session is removed.
